# SqlCommand - Select ISNULL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Hello I'm trying to `select * data` but for column named `payments` if is NULL  I need to insert set value `0`.

I tried to do it like this:

```
string sqlcom = "SELECT (ISNULL(payments,0)) * FROM zajezd WHERE id >= '" + txt_od.Text + "'AND id <='" + txt_do.Text + "' AND year='" + klientClass.Rocnik() + "'";
```

But I'm still receiving exception `bad syntax near FROM`

Would somebody help me solve this out please?

Thanks so much in advance

Comment: next time try to post `sqlcom` value and assignement :)

Comment: You should also specify a column alias, e.g.: `SELECT payments=ISNULL(payments,0) ...`. Also, you mention that `s_prijmy` might be null but you check `payments` instead, just a typo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put `,` before `*`. Try this

```
string sqlcom = "SELECT (ISNULL(payments,0)), * FROM zajezd WHERE id >= '" + txt_od.Text + "'AND id <='" + txt_do.Text + "' AND year='" + klientClass.Rocnik() + "'";
```

But I would also suggest you to not to pass the parameter like this. Use `Parameterized query` to avoid sql injection.

Comment: I would add that it's often considered bad practice to use * in production code as it means your code can be broken by reordering the table's columns. Naming them explicitly is much safer.

Comment: Thank you, May I ask if there is way to return ´0,00´ ?

Comment: You can but I'd suggest another question ;-)  I'm assuming what you mean is to return it as a decimal rather than an integer?

Comment: Yes exactly, when the value is just 0 the converting as reader.GetDecimal(..) will throw an exception ? I tried to insert it like (ISNULL(payments, 0,00)), * FROM .. but it gone with část is not valid at get_Decimal() . May you propose me how can I return the decimal of 0,00 please ?

Comment: @Marek You need to open a new question, or this one will wander off topic

Answer (score 3):

You need a comma or clear the `*`.

```
SELECT (ISNULL(payments,0)), * FROM
```

or

```
SELECT (ISNULL(payments,0)) FROM
```

Just to add the sum of the commends (Thanks to Liath) you should not use `*`. Instead specify which columns you really need.

Also remove the external parenthesis as they are not really needed.

I would also add that you should use an allias for that column.

So it would be:

```
SELECT ISNULL(payments,0) AS payments, Col1, Col2,..., Coln FROM...
```

or just plain:

```
SELECT ISNULL(payments,0) AS payments FROM...
```

Comment: To expand, the * represents "All Columns", as the IsNull creates a column you need to add a comma between it and the others.  Also, personally I'd drop the brackets around the IsNull section, it makes it complicated for no reason.

Comment: @Liath Totally aggreed

Comment: Sorry to hijack your answer - there didn't seem any point in creating yet another to say the same thing!

Answer (score 2):

Add comma between

```
(ISNULL(payments,0))
```

and

```
*
```

Answer (score 1):

Either you remove the `*` or you put a comma in between `(ISNULL(payments,0))` and `*`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
string sqlcom = "SELECT ISNULL(payments,0), * FROM zajezd WHERE id >= '" + txt_od.Text + "'AND id <='" + txt_do.Text + "' AND year='" + klientClass.Rocnik() + "'";
```

Your `WHERE` clause is a bit ambigious. `<= txt_do.Text AND >= txt_od.Text`

That will not filter anything out